# Why can't beamer skip white spaces when looking for \end{frame} in a fragile frame?

Tags: beamer

We all know that when using a fragile frame in `beamer` one has to be careful to make the `\end{frame}` command appear exactly at the beginning of the line. I understand why the problem arises: the contents of the environment have to be written to a file, so beamer has to scan everything until `\end{frame}` to collect the tokens that have to be written.

But I don't understand, and can't find anywhere, the reason why the `\end{frame}` sequence of tokens have to be exactly at the beginning of the line. Why can't beamer at least skip white spaces at the beginning of the line when looking for this token sequence?

I suppose there must be some TeXnical reasons for why beamer can't do this seemingly simple thing. Can you summarize which are those reasons?

Answer (score 6):

The current test used in `beamer` to find the end-of-frame is set up in `\beamer@processframeline`

```
  \long\gdef\beamer@processframeline#1^^M{%
    \def\beamer@test{#1}%
    \ifx\beamer@test\beamer@stopframe%
      \let\next=\beamer@framewritten%
    \else%
      \immediate\write\beamer@verbatimfileout{#1}%
      \let\next=\beamer@processframeline%
    \fi%
    \next%
  }%
```

As pointed out by [Piet van Oostrum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/343722) this relies on the nature of the grabbed line being identical to that of the 'reference' (`\beamer@stopframe`).

This is of course technically solvable, one simply has to put in additional effort. For example, a loop can be used to remove spaces at the start of the grabbed line:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
{\catcode`\^^M=12\endlinechar=-1%
  \long\gdef\beamer@processframeline#1^^M{%
    \edef\beamer@test{\beamer@spacestrip#1\beamer@stop}%
    \ifx\beamer@test\beamer@stopframe%
      \let\next=\beamer@framewritten%
    \else%
      \immediate\write\beamer@verbatimfileout{#1}%
      \let\next=\beamer@processframeline%
    \fi%
    \next%
  }%
}
\begingroup
\catcode`\ =12\relax%
\gdef\beamer@spacestrip#1{%
\ifx#1\beamer@stop\else%
\ifx#1 \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\beamer@spacestrip%
\else%
\noexpand#1%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\beamer@strip@end%
\fi%
\fi%
}%
\endgroup%
\def\beamer@strip@end#1\beamer@stop{\unexpanded{#1}}
\def\beamer@stop{\beamer@stop}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
Hello world
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

(Tabs can also be covered but as they won't paste into the site properly I've omitted that code.)

This is currently down to be looked at as [issue #326](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/326) in `beamer`, and depending on design decisions (what should and should not be skipped) will be fixed in the next release.

---

Note that the above does allow for a 'nested' verbatim demo of an end frame, for example as

```
\newenvironment{slide}
  {\begin{frame}[fragile,environment=slide]}
  {\end{frame}}

\begin{slide}{My title}
  Text.
  \begin{verbatim}
    \end{frame}
  \end{verbatim}
\end{slide}
```

Comment: although if you test after stripping white space then it is harder to have any way of having the string`\end{frame}` (eg in nested verbatim) unless you go the whole way and match all \begin/\end by hand. currently it works to have nested instances as long as they are indented.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, that is an issue (although arguably less common than the one where people indent frames). There are far more people using `beamer` for 'stuff' than for documenting/demonstrating `beamer` itself! Counting up by hand is a possible I suppose ...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle As far as I can understand, If one needs to write \end{frame} verbatim (say, in a deck of slides about Beamer itself) then one may use a new environment and change environment name with the environment option. Right?

Comment: @gigabytes no it would be rather difficult to do that at all unless beamer provided some new "escape" mechanism.

Comment: Why? If I say environment=foo, then Beamer looks for \end{foo} and I can write \end{frame} verbatim inside the frame. I'm not at the PC right now so I cannot test but I don't see why it couldn't work.

Comment: @gigabytes oh perhaps you are right:-)

Answer (score 4):

Beamer reads a frame in fragile (verbatim) mode one line at a time. Then it checks if that line is exactly `\end{frame}`, or `\end{xxxx}` when the `environment=xxxx` option is given.  The test is done with a simple TeX `\ifx` command.

Apparently it wasn't deemed worth the extra effort to allow additional spaces in front of the `\end`.

Comment: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/326: I am thinking about it! (A long list of `beamer` things to do)